# cannot update postgres db from 9.3 to 9.4 in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cloudformation

I have created a RDS instance with postgres9.3.14 with Db paramgroup of 9.3 family. (through CFN template).Now , I am trying to upgrade the Db version to 9.4.11 through CFN , the upgrade is failing with below error.

DBParameterGroupFamily postgres9.3 cannot be used for this instance. Please use a Parameter Group with DBParameterGroupFamily postgres9.4

From the AWS documentation, I understood that I cannot update family of a parameter group once it is created. 
I want to understand,If I try to update the Db version from 9.3 to 9.4, Does the CFN has that intelligence to delete existing DB parameter group(9.3 family) creates a new parameter group (9.4 family)with correct family?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

try this method.
create new parameter group which belongs to postgresql 9.4, then attach newly created parameter group to RDS now start the upgrade process.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But we use CFN templates to do the updates as it is a automated process. We dont create resource outside of CFN template.